# how can I solve "column count doesn't match value at row 1" on reader.read in c#

Tags: c#

the error "column count doesn't match value at row 1" is cached on "reader.HasRows"

```
command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("NAME", itemNameTextBox.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("DESCRIPTION", descriptionTextBox.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("TYPE", Convert.ToString(typeCombo.SelectedValue)));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("UNIT", Convert.ToString(unitComo.SelectedValue)));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("PROJECT", projectTextBox.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("ISNEW", isNewRadio.Checked));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("EXPIRYDATE", expiryDatePicker.Value.Date));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("PROJECTEXPIRY", projectExpiryPicker.Value.Date));
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                }
```

Comment: your SQL has more or less parameters than you provide here. post your SQL

Comment: Post the whole code for us to identify your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this

- Provided the full required data. If you omit the column names when inserting data, make sure to provide a full row of data that matches the number of columns. ...
- Specify the columns to be inserted in case not all columns are going to have value.
- you missed the comma between two values or column name
- you put extra values or an extra column name